# Is it possible to start WCF UDP Listener in IIS on a shared host without requiring a user to access HTTP first?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, udp, shared-hosting

I have created a sweet ASP.NET 4.0 UDP listener via WCF that starts on Application_Start.  As usual, everything is hunky dory on my local machine.  On my local machine using the VS Dev Environment and setting it to not open any page upon debug, the listener starts without browsing to anything yet.  However, whenever I deploy to my shared host, I must access the site via a web browser before the listener will start.  I do not have access to the IIS control panel but I do have some limited setting changes I can make to IIS via "Website Panel" software.  I believe the shared host uses IIS 7.5.

Is there a better way to solve this rather than creating a polling service from my home PC to send an HTTP request to the shared host every so often to kick off the listener?

Requirements

- The client sends UDP packets over a configurable port. I cannot change anything other than the IP and port that the client uses to connect
- The solution must work with my shared host since I cannot afford a VPS at this time - otherwise I would've created a Windows Service. I got around creating a window service before by creating a polling service via WCF Application_Start but that only works because the info the users would see have to be on a webpage therefore application_start would always be called.  In this case, the users/clients are not necessarily accessing the webpage.

Ideas:

- Somehow pull this into a .svc. That way when the .svc is accessed by the client, it kicks off the listener for everyone else. But how can a .svc running on port 80 accept UDP calls?  I'm also not sure if the client will be able to connect to more than an IP:PORT (I don't think it'd accept a .svc path like URL.com/awesomeListener.svc).

Any suggestions?  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ASP.NET 4.0 you can set it to auto-start for you which will fire Application_Start:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: Zippit, you'll see in my post that a requirement is a shared host.  Your answer was promising at first, but I don't think it'll work in a shared hosting scenario since it's a host-level configuration and not a application-level one.

Comment: Confirmed:  Host won't allow the change.